# Google Translate not working on my site

Tags: wordpress, google-translate

I'm currently developing a website and I have been asked to implement google translate in it, however when i try to translate some thing the website completely breaks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug5bI.jpg

any solution why?

When I try a manual translation (right click - translate to english) it works

I'm using wordpress with a theme based on uikit

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after debuggind the code I found out the problem:
In custom.css I put iframe{width:100% !important; height:100% !important;}, deleting them solved the problem